# Using multiple image modals, help convert from jquery library to bootstrap library

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

So I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56777139/opening-a-modal-on-click-image-with-multiple-images-using-single-modal--) regarding using multiple image modals on a page. However I am assuming that this question was strictly made for javascript and jQuery. I am using the latest version of Bootstrap and I was wondering if this can be rewritten to fit my project. I have about 8 images I would like to be displayed individually and not connected to each other such as in a Carousel. Preferably I would like to use one full screen modal that takes the components of the 8 pictures and display them. Sorry for the confusion before. Can the code below, be rewritten without the jQuery library using Bootstrap components.

This is the jQuery code from the question:

```
var modal = $("#myModal");
var modalImg = modal.find('.modal-content');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = $(".myImg");
var captionBox = $("#caption");

img.click(function() {
  modalImg.attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
  captionBox.text($(this).attr('alt'));
  modal.show();
});

// Get the elements that closes the modal
var modalCloser = $(".close");

// When the user clicks on the close element, close the modal
modalCloser.click(function() {
  modal.hide();
});
```

This is the HTML code from the question:

```
<!-- Trigger the Modal -->
<img class="myImg" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?random=1" 
alt="Snow" onclick="image(event)" style="width:100%;max- 
width:300px" />

<img class="myImg" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?random=2" 
alt="Snow" onclick="image(event)" style="width:100%;max- 
width:300px" />

<img class="myImg" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?random=3" 
alt="Snow" onclick="image(event)" style="width:100%;max- 
width:300px" />

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- The Close Button -->
    <span class="close">&times;</span>

    <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
    <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

    <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
    <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Is it possible to rewrite this jQuery code into Bootstrap" - If by Bootstrap you mean Javascript, then yes, it is possible to write any jQuery as Javascript, given jQuery is just a Javascript library.

Comment: I don't understand the snarky comments here. The code was originally written using jquery UI and now the author would like to know how it could be done in bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow what you're asking, you'd like to see an example of using bootstrap to popup a modal with an image when it's clicked on.

There are many ways of doing this, but I've coded up an example that shows one possible way.

```js
let modal = $("#myModal");

// listen to an image click
$(".myImg").click(function() {
  // Set the src of the img embedded in the dialog
  modal.find("img").attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
  // Set the modal title using the alt text of the selected image
  $("#exampleModalLabel").text($(this).attr('alt'));
  // show the modal
  modal.modal("show");
});
```

```css
/* modifying the dialog style to only be as large as the img it contains */

.modal-dialog {
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto !important;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* center the dialog on the page */

.modal {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.6.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha512-BmM0/BQlqh02wuK5Gz9yrbe7VyIVwOzD1o40yi1IsTjriX/NGF37NyXHfmFzIlMmoSIBXgqDiG1VNU6kB5dBbA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-UR25UO94eTnCVwjbXozyeVd6ZqpaAE9naiEUBK/A+QDbfSTQFhPGj5lOR6d8tsgbBk84Ggb5A3EkjsOgPRPcKA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-T584yQ/tdRR5QwOpfvDfVQUidzfgc2339Lc8uBDtcp/wYu80d7jwBgAxbyMh0a9YM9F8N3tdErpFI8iaGx6x5g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <img class="myImg" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?random=1" alt="Snow" style="width: 100%; max-width: 300px;" />

    <img class="myImg" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?random=2" alt="Snow" style="width: 100%; max-width: 300px;" />

    <img class="myImg" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?random=3" alt="Snow" style="width: 100%; max-width: 300px;" />

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <img/>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="src/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```